# Update MySQL table in PHP with Ajax in POST mode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to do an update :

here is my js script in my php page :

```
            alert ("Ench : " + idE + " Price : "+ pf2 +" idU : " + idU); 
            $.ajax({
                url: './update.php', //same place in the server
                type : 'POST',
                data : 'id_enchere=' + idE + '&idU=' + idU + '&prix=' + pf2,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function() {
                        return false;
                    }
            });
```

The alert(..) confirm that my values are filled.

here is my PHP page called : **update.php**

```
$query=$db->prepare('UPDATE enchere SET id_membre_act = :idU, prix_actuel = :prix WHERE id = :id_enchere');
$query->bindValue(':id_enchere', $_POST['id_enchere'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':idU', $_POST['idU'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':prix', $_POST['prix'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

I already do select and insert in my db so the connection is good.

I'm new in php and js/ajax programming.
I don't understand why it doesn't work.
i try to put this in the called page :

```
$file = fopen('./files/test.txt', 'w+');
```

And no file was created. So i think my page is not called.

Thanks for any help.

Guillaume.

Comment: Isn't more simple you debug your php code by printing any value instead of creating a text file? like: `print_r($_POST)` before the update?

Comment: You say it's the same place in the server so replace `'./update.php',` with `'update.php',`

Comment: Another way to easily debug an AJAX call is to use chrome's built-in debugger(opened by pressing F12). You then go to the network tab and you'll see the queries as well as their result. That's super helpful.

Comment: I dont display update.php so print_r($_POST) will not dispkay anything for me ?
I tried also with just 'update.php'. (same result)
I will try with F12, i was just looking the console tab and nothing was display in.

Comment: You should watch the Network tab, reload the page and click your post button if any

Comment: I have a POST request, with green button so it seems to work. but still nothing is updated :/

Comment: The POST request in maybe my own first page which is reloading. Even i put return false; the page reload so i dont know for which page is my POST request

Comment: @guiolgui have you fixed the above issue?

Comment: Yes but i dont know how i solve my issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem but i dont know how :/
i have the same code and now it works.
Thanks for your help.

Guiolgui